# image gallery CRUD - update function deletes existing file even if no replacement is selected

Tags: php, crud

I am making making a dynamic image gallery using PHP, all my CRUD is functioning as expected, except when I update an image's details (title & description), if no new image file i selected, the old one is still deleted. 
PHP code is as follows:

```
    $id = null;
if( !empty($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}

if( null == $id){
  header("location: galleryadmin.php");
}

if (!empty($_POST)){
    $uploader = new Uploader();

    //keep track of validation errors
    $titleError = null;
    $descriptionError = null;
    $imageError = null;

    //track post values
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];

    //validating inputs
    $valid = true;

    if(empty($title)){
        $titleError = 'Please add a title';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if(empty($description)){
        $descriptionError = 'Please add a description';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['title']) && !$uploader->valid($_FILES['image'])){
        $imageError = 'Invalid file uploaded';
        $valid = false;
    }

    //update data
    if($valid){

        if (!empty($image)){
            $uploader->delete($image);
        }

        $image = $uploader->upload($_FILES['image']);

        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "UPDATE gallery set title = ?, description = ?, image = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($title,$description,$image,$id));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("location: galleryadmin.php");
    }

} else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $title = $data['title'];
    $description = $data['description'];
    $image = $data['image'];
    Database::disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the form element called `"image"` is of type `"file"` then you can not access it with `$_POST['image']` - you can only access it through `$_FILES['image']`
So your check

```
if (!empty($image)){
```

is wrong. Instead, use this

```
if(is_array($_FILES) AND count($_FILES['image'])!=0 AND $_FILES['image']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
```

Comment: "image" does not store the file itself, just the image path, does this change things?

Comment: I am not sure that I properly understand your last comment. When you look at the web form on the screen - yes, the form element of type `"file"` looks like the form elements of type `"text"` and shows the local path of the file which would be uploaded. But when the server receives the form, it actually contains both the name AND the content of the file. So, `$_POST['image']` would be always empty regardless if there was or was not uploaded a file - because it is not an ordinary form element, but a file. And files are accessed using the `$_FILES` super-global.